# Pattern no longer working when moving SVG to an external file

Tags: svg, svg-pattern

Here's an SVG. If you add this directly to your HTML page, it will render nicely. Note that the folder's right-hand side has a subtle shadow that's done with a black and white checker pattern.

```html
<svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        version="1.1"
        width="96px"
        height="48px"
        viewBox="0 0 48 24"
        enable-background="new 0 0 48 24"
        id="svg"
    >
        <defs>
            <pattern id="checkers" x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <rect style="fill: #000" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"></rect>
                <rect style="fill: #000" x="1" y="1" width="1" height="1"></rect>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <path
            d="M 1 6 l 8 -4 l 37 0 v 12 l -5 8"
            style="fill: #fff; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1px"
        />
        <path d="M 45.5 2 L 45.5 14 l -5 8" 
            style="fill: url(#checkers); stroke: none;"
        />
        <path 
            d="M 1 6 h 40 v 16 h -40 v -16" 
            style="fill: #fff; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1px"
        />
        <path
            d="M 4 9 h 34 v 10 h -34 v -10"
            style="fill: transparent; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1px"
        />
        <path
            d="M 17.5 13.5 l -1.5 1.5 l 8 0 l 1.5 -1.5 M 46 2 L 41 6" 
            style="fill: transparent; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 1px"
        />
    </svg>
```

I want to move this to an external file. I reference it from HTML like this:

```
<svg width="64px" height="64px">
    <use xlink:href="./svg/drawer.svg#svg" />
</svg>
```

However, when referenced like this, the SVG will render, but **the pattern no longer works**. The drawer's right-hand side is just white and does not show the checker pattern. I suspect `url(#checkers)` cannot be used within an external file. How do I do this instead?

Comment: Are you serving the files from a web server?

Comment: Yes, from Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working by using the `object` or `img` tag rather than `svg` with `use`. In HTML, I write:

```
<object data="./svg/drawer.svg#svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Or:

```
<img src="./svg/drawer.svg#svg" width="96px" height="48px"></img>
```

The latter variant is probably better, because you can add an onClick handler to an `img`, but not to an `object`.

I have no idea why this works and `svg` doesn't, so it would be good to know if someone the reason.